# Simple BMR calculator HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the beginning of my term paper.
What is wrong and why?

My calculator doesn't show the result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script>

var bmr;
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
var weigth = document.getElementById("weigth").value;

if (gender == "masc") {
bmr = 66.5 + ( 13.75 * weigth ) + ( 5.003 * height ) – ( 6.755 * age )
}
else {
bmr = 655.1 + ( 9.563 * weigth ) + ( 1.850 * height ) – ( 4.676 * age )
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" id="gender" value="masc" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" id="gender" value="fem"> Female<br>
  Age:<br>
  <input type="number" id="age" value="20"><br>
  Height:<br>
  <input type="number" id="height" value="180"><br>
  Weight:<br>
  <input type="number" id="weigth" value="80"><br>
</form>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = bmr">
Result</button>

<p id="lblResult">BMR</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the `–` character you've used in `– ( 6.755 * age )` and `– ( 4.676 * age )` are not minus signs, they're some other sort of dash character, so that's why you get the "Invalid...token" error - delete those and type them again with the `-` key on your keyboard. I'm voting to close this as having been caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: (P.S. The *next* problem will be that you are calling `document.getElementById()` in a script in the `<head>` which runs *before* the browser has parsed your elements, but really you need to put that code inside a function that you can call from the button click event so that the calculation uses the currently entered values.)

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn and Antonio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment mentioned you have a dash instead of a minus sign in your code preventing it from working.

`bmr = 66.5 + ( 13.75 * weigth ) + ( 5.003 * height ) here-> - ( 6.755 * age )`

You will also have to move your script to the end of the html file, just before the closing `</body>` tag beacause in your code when you select the elements they are not loaded so it dosen't work.

And the onclick event wont work the way you intended, its better if you make event inside the script.

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", 
 function() {
   calc();
   document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = bmr;

 })
```

You sould also move the calculation code inside a function so you can calculate the values again, as it stands whenever you click result you will get the same value.

Here is a working [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/XRWYWg).